# Add days to a date without changing GMT time

Tags: javascript, date

I am working on an application where all dates used are round GMT dates, e.g. `2015-10-29T00:00:00.000Z`.

I am using following function to add days to a date :

```
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  return result;
}
```

But, I just realized it doesn't work when crossing daylight saving time changing day :

```
var myDate = new Date('2015-10-24T00:00:00.000Z');
for(i = 0; i<4; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(myDate));
  myDate = addDays(myDate, 1);
}
```

Outputs this :

```
"2015-10-24T00:00:00.000Z"
"2015-10-25T00:00:00.000Z"
"2015-10-26T01:00:00.000Z"
             ^
"2015-10-27T01:00:00.000Z"
             ^
```

Note that the two last dates are not round anymore.

What is the proper way to deal with this ?

Comment: Use http://www.datejs.com it is very powerfull and handles most if the scenarios ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Date.setDate()` adds a day without changing the **local** time. But this means the GMT time does change !

Using `Date.setUTCDate()` solves the problem :

```
function addUTCDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setUTCDate(result.getUTCDate() + days);
  //        ^^^               ^^^
  return result;
}
```

Then :

```
var myDate = new Date('2015-10-24T00:00:00.000Z');
for(i = 0; i<4; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(myDate));
  myDate = addUTCDays(myDate, 1);
}
```

Outputs this :

```
"2015-10-24T00:00:00.000Z"
"2015-10-25T00:00:00.000Z"
"2015-10-26T00:00:00.000Z"
"2015-10-27T00:00:00.000Z"
```

This will also work for months :

```
function addMonths(date, months) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setUTCMonth(result.getUTCMonth() + months);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Actually I found a solution that is definitely better. I'm leaving this for the sake of exhaustivity.

The problem is that `Date.setDate()` adds a day without changing the **local** time. But this means the GMT time does change !

Adding a day without changing the GMT time is actually as simple as adding 24 * 3600 * 1000 milliseconds to the date's time :

```
function addGMTDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setTime(result.getTime() + days * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
  return result;
}
```

Then :

```
var myDate = new Date('2015-10-24T00:00:00.000Z');
for(i = 0; i<4; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(myDate));
  myDate = addGMTDays(myDate, 1);
}
```

Outputs this :

```
"2015-10-24T00:00:00.000Z"
"2015-10-25T00:00:00.000Z"
"2015-10-26T00:00:00.000Z"
"2015-10-27T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: I had to convert the integer values to LONG to avoid truncations